What exactly xcodebuild -resolvePackageDependencies does?
I added some dependencies via SPM to a react native project I am working on. It auto generated Package.resolve file. The project also has podspec.lock. When I run pod install, the package.resolved file gets deleted, but once I run
xcodebuild -resolvePackageDependencies -workspace ./Inji.xcworkspace -scheme Inji -configuration Release -destination "generic/platform=iOS Simulator"

It gets regenerated.
I wanted to know, what this command does, what it looks for, and on a broader aspect how to manage dependency using SPM and cocoapods simultaneously. I have CI pipeline setup, so solution should not be IDE specific.
I basically expect that the file does not regenerate each time, and it does not get deleted either.

Why do you care whether Package.resolved gets recreated? Why is it bad if it is? (And isn't that exactly what you asked Xcode to do?)

We are a team of developers, and want to use same version of each dependency. On recreation it might get resolved to different versions.

Why would that happen? Look, the same thing happens every time you run your project too. So if this is not a problem when each of you works on the project, it isn't a problem when CI (or whatever) builds it.
